# TabBarView showing hasSize error yet I dont want to use Sizebox

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to show a tabview in between widgets in flutter, but I keep getting the hasSize error. I don't want to limit the tabview to size, because I want its height to adjust according to the content I want to put in there so that it doesn't show a blank space between it and the next widget if the content in there is little. Kindly someone help

Here is the tabview

```
Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 36,
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.grey[300],
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        25.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: TabBar(
                      controller: tabController,
                      indicator: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                          25.0,
                        ),
                        color: kPremium,
                      ),
                      labelColor: Colors.white,
                      unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                      tabs: const [
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Transactions',
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: 'Activities',
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: Dimensions.sizeDefault),
                  Expanded(
                    child: TabBarView(
                      controller: tabController,
                      physics:
                          const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // Add this
                      children: [
                        // first tab bar view widget

                        spaceController.spaceTransactionList.isNotEmpty
                            ? ListView.builder(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                physics:
                                    const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // Add this
                                shrinkWrap: true, // Add this
                                itemCount: spaceController
                                    .spaceTransactionList.length,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                  var transaction = spaceController
                                      .spaceTransactionList[index];
                                  return SpaceTransactionItem(
                                      transaction: transaction);
                                },
                              )
                            : Column(
                                children: [
                                  if (spaceController.spaceLoading.value ||
                                      spaceController
                                          .spacetransLoading.value)
                                    ...transactionShimmers,
                                  if (!spaceController
                                          .spacetransLoading.value &&
                                      !spaceController.spaceLoading.value)
                                    const NotFound(
                                        notFoundText: "Transactions")
                                ],
                              ),
```

And here is the parent page

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
          statusBarColor: Colors.black, // set the status bar color
          statusBarIconBrightness:
              Brightness.light, // set the status bar text color
        ),
        child: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: kBackground,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  bottom: 30,
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top,
                  left: Dimensions.sizeLarge,
                  right: Dimensions.sizeLarge,
                ),
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                      color: kBorder,
                      width: 1,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                child: const Column(children: [
                  SpaceAppbar(),
                  SizedBox(height: Dimensions.sizeOverLarge * 3),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 180,
                    child: SpaceHeader(),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
              SpaceActivity(
                tabController: tabController,
              ),
              SharedVault(),
            ],
          )),
        ));
  }
```

The widget is the one called SpaceActivity, and you can see its above SpaceVault, which is also another widget

Comment: The error persists